# How do I show that $(A \cup B) \times C = (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$ holds for all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ using mathematical logic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I understand how this is true, as the entirety of the elements in sets A and B multiplied by C would be equivalent to the combination of A x C and B x C. My problem is that I am having trouble expressing this in proper predicate or first-order logic, or any type of logic for that matter.

Any insight on how to properly prove/express this statement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Suppose $x \in (A \cup B) \times C$. Then the first coordinate of $x$ is in $A$ or in $B$, possibly both, and the second coordinate is in $C$. If the first coordinate is in $A$, then since the second is in $C$, $x$ by definition belongs to $A \cup C$; otherwise, the first coordinate is in $B$ and we find $x \in B \cup C$. Therefore $x \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$; but since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude $(A \cup B) \times C \subseteq (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$. Now we will show $(A \cup B) \times C \supseteq (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$, and we will be done...."

Comment: ^ is how part of the proof would go, and I'll let you finish the rest!

Comment: You could also do "Suppose $(x,y)\in(A{\cup}B){\times} C$..."

Comment: To a categorist, this is just a special case of "left adjoints preserve colimits". To a categorist, the $(P\lor Q)\land R \iff (P\land R)\lor(Q\land R)$ that is at the heart of Omnomnomnom's answer is *also* a special case of "left adjoints preserve colimits"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to proving that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal is showing that $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in B$.

First, we show that $x \in (A \cup B) \times C \implies (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$.  By definition, $x \in (A \cup B) \times C$ means that $x$ is an ordered pair $x = (x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1 \in A \cup B$ and $x_2 \in C$.  If we apart that union, we have $x_1 \in A$ or $x_1 \in B$.  All together, we have
$$
(x_1 \in A \text{ or } x_1 \in B) \text{ and } x_2 \in C
$$
This is logically equivalent to 
$$
(x_1 \in A \text{ and } x_2 \in C) \text{ or } (x_1 \in B \text{ and } x_2 \in C)
$$
In practice, one usually does not need to prove this equivalence explicitly (especially on a test question, for example).  However, it may be shown that these are equivalent with a truth table.

Of course, $(x_1 \in A \text{ and } x_2 \in C) \text{ or } (x_1 \in B \text{ and } x_2 \in C)$ means that the pair $x = (x_1,x_2)$ is an element of $(A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$, by definition.

It remains to be shown that these steps can be reversed, i.e. that $(A \times C) \cup (B \times C) \implies x \in (A \cup B) \times C$.

Comment: I don't think the steps have to be reversed since all steps use logically equivalent sentences. Thus you have shown that $x \in (A \cup B) \times C \iff (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$

Answer (score 0):

By first principles:

$$
\begin{align}
(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times C &\iff (x \in (A \cup B)) \land (y \in C) \\
&\iff ((x \in A) \lor (x \in B)) \land (y \in C) \\
&\iff ((x \in A) \land (y \in C)) \lor ((x \in B)) \land (y \in C)) \\
&\iff ((x,y) \in A \times C) \lor ((x,y) \in B \times C) \\
&\iff (x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)
\end{align}     
$$